# How do I rename images when using mogrify with Image Magick?

Tags: bash, imagemagick, mogrify

I am trying to automate the converting images to specified tif formats. I have it converting just fine, but am also needing to add "_GS" at the end of the file name and before the extension to each file converted. Below is what I have but have had no luck finding a solution to add "_GS" to the file name. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
for f in "$@"
do
    echo "$f"
/usr/local/bin/mogrify -density 300 -resize 1000x1000 -type grayscale -define tiff:endian=msb -compress LZW -format tif "$f" [0] 
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item 1: With Image Magick, to create a new file instead of overwriting an existing one, use `convert`, not `mogrify` (`magick convert` with newer versions of IM).

Item 2: You can use shell parameter expansion to remove the extension, and then build the new filename from that and the new suffix:

```sh
for f in "$@"
do
    echo "$f"
    /usr/local/bin/convert "$f" -density 300 -resize 1000x1000 -type grayscale \
      -define tiff:endian=msb -compress LZW -format tif "${f%.*}_GS.tiff"
done
```

`${variable%pattern}` returns the expansion of `variable` with the shortest match of `pattern` removed from the end.

Comment: Note moving the original filename's position in the arguments to `convert`, and splitting it up into two lines for readability.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is working except the result is creating an additional file. 4.ext changes to 4_GS.tiff and then another file is created 4_GS_GS.tiff

Comment: Sounds like you're running it multiple times on all the files in a directory.

Comment: Sorry I am a little new to scripting, but i can't seem to figure out why it is running a 2nd time. I am using automator with a folder action. the only thing I can think of is when it creates the first *_GS.tif, the folder sees it as a new file and runs the script again. But if that were the case wouldn't it be infinite? So close, again i appreciate your help.

Comment: Better to write a simple script loop over convert. Convert is much more flexible than the old mogrify.

Comment: I was able to achieve my desired results by moving to another directory. It was producing multiple files due to automator running again due to input into the hot folder from the action.